# Rendering happening everyime a button is pressed inside a map

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this map that shows different buttons, everytime i press one of them, the alert gets triggered or actually any function that returns something gets triggered.
Why this happens?

```
{activitiesObject.map((data, i) => (
                            <TouchableOpacity key={data.activity} onPress={() => toggleSelectedActivity(i)}>
                                <Text style={selectedActivity ? styles.selectedTag : styles.tagsText}>{data.activity}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        ))}
```

I want everytime i press some of the buttons the re-rendering dont happen or the alert dont gets triggered.

snack https://snack.expo.io/DSwQPPn3x9

Comment: You're mapping a bunch of `TouchableOpacty` elements, each one with its own `onPress` function, which calls `toggleSelectedActivity`.  Is that not what you want to do?

Comment: the problem is that the alert is being called when I press one of them, i dont want that

Comment: the alert('test') is not inside the toggleSelectedActivity function so i pressume that a re-render is happening, but i dont know why

Comment: so, you need to create parent-child component if you don't want to re-render (parent component), when the button pressed (child component)

Answer (score 1):

you are calling **toggleSelectedActivity** on every onpress which is calling **setSelectedActivity** which is **updating state**.
there is a rule in react whenever we update state re-rendering will happen.